# Problems retrieving token in response header - Angular 6 - backend Spring

Tags: spring, angular, header

Dev. enviroment: Angular 6.0.9 - Spring boot 2.0.7 - Spring 5.0.7

I have a boring problem. My angular application can not see the token that comes in the request header. my backend is spring and by postman I usually get the token. it is worth noting that in the (chrome) browser, the status code is 200.

Token generetor:

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String login = ((UsuarioSS) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername();
    String token = jwtUtil.generateToken(login);
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
    response.addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

}
```

Service login:

```
export class LoginService {

  constructor(public http: HttpClient) { }

  authenticate(credential: Credential) {
    return this.http.post(`${API_URL}/sge/login`,credential,{observe:'response',responseType:'text'});
  }
}
```

Component:

```
 onSubmit(){
this.credential = this.loginForm.value;
this.loginService.authenticate(this.credential).subscribe(
  response => {
    console.log(response)
  },
  error => {console.log(error)}
)
```

CONSOLE CHROME:
[image]

CONSOLE POSTMAN:

[image]

Comment: can you try `console.log(response.headers.get('Authorization'))` instead of `console.log(response)` ?

Comment: I also tried this and got 'null'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I was not realizing that the custom headers were coming as LazyInit. After that I was able to access my header with the token.